# How to train OpenCV SVM classifier on images

Tags: python, image, opencv

The purpose of the task is to classify images by means of SVM. The variable 'images' is supposed to contain the image information and correspondingly `labels` contains image labels. How can I build (what format and dimensions) should the `images` and `labels` have? I tried unsuccesfully `images` to be a Python array (appending flattened images) and then, in another attempt, Numpy arrays:

```
images=np.zeros((number_of_images, image_size))
labels=np.zeros((number_of_images, 1))

svm=cv2.SVM()
svm.train(images, labels)
```

Is it a right approach to the problem and if so, what is the correct way for training the classifier?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you can use raw image data to train SVM model. Ok-ok, you **can**, but it won't be very fruitful.

The basic approach is to **extract** some **features** from each image and to use these features for training your model. A set of features forms a dictionary of words, each of which describes your image. Due to the fact that you are using the same set of words to describe each image, you can compare features corresponding to different images. [This link](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~az/icvss08_az_bow.pdf) introduces more details, check it.

Whats next?

1. Choose a feature extractor for your algo - HOG, SURF, SIFT ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_(computer_vision)))
2. Extract features from each image. You'll get an array of the same length as images array.
3. Initialize bag-of-words (BoG) model
4. Train SVM with BoG

Useful links:

1. [C++ vey detailed example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/619039/Bag-of-Features-Descriptor-on-SIFT-Features-with-O)
2. [Documentation for existing BOG classifier](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/features2d/doc/object_categorization.html)

Comment: You could use raw image data to train SVM model which is very fruitful. For example, R,G,B / L,a,b channels to train a model for color correction.

Comment: @RickM. But we are discussing classification, aren't we?